# Scan QR Code using appium, python and robotframework

Tags: python, mobile, automation, appium, robotframework

I am trying to automate scanning screen to scan QR code in an android application - currently using appium, python and robotframework.

Here are the steps: When I click on a button, it should open a scanning screen. I then scan a QR code. On successful scanning, a unique number will displayed in one of the field in the scanning screen and then I can click on Done button and that takes to next screen.

There are few things I tried:

- Zxing library: Using this library I was able to locate the QR code image in local machine and able to retrieve the unique number from it. However, when I try to insert/put this number into the scanning screen, **it does not allow me as the locaters as is_displayed of the the locators is FALSE. **
- Tried camera injection using SauseLabs. I wanted to try manually before I start writing automation scripts. I tried insert the image manually into one of the real device. I get the green message saying its successfully inserted. However, I** do not see the Unique number being acummulated on the screen**.

**Please suggest a best way to make this work. **